# How to send email/trigger parameterized remote job based on error category from Build Failure Analyzer Jenkins plugin?

Tags: jenkins

I want to categorize different types of errors appearing in the console output of Jenkins using the [Build Failure Analyzer plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-failure-analyzer/). If there aren't any errors caught by that plugin, then I want to trigger another job using [Parameterized Remote trigger plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/Parameterized-Remote-Trigger/). Else, I want to send an email to the concerned team describing all the attributes in the failure cause of that plugin (e.g. Name in that Failure Cause and the corresponding error text which got printed in the failure logs).

[Build Failure Analyzer window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIXyp.png)

For example, if the console output of different failure logs show the following errors:

1. You don't have the required permissions to copy this file.
2. java.lang.NullPointerException
   at Login.processLogin(Login.java:68)

I want to categorize these errors based on the analyzer plugin and if caught by that plugin, I want to send an email:
**e.g. Build #48 at {My_Jenkins_Job_Url} failed due to Permission denied (Failure cause Name). You don't have the required permissions to copy this file (console log text).**

If not caught and successful, then I should be able to trigger parameterized remote Jenkins job.

I am just a beginner with regards to Jenkins. It would be better if anyone explains and assists me with complete details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it something like this, you can parse Jenkins console output which will look for this error message, you have to add the condition in your jenkinsfile

```
if (manager.logContains('.*You don't have the required permissions to copy this file.*') || (manager.logContains('.*java.lang.NullPointerException at Login.processLogin(Login.java:68).*'))) {
      emailext body: 'Build failure', subject: 'Build failure', to: 'test@ab.org'  
  }
```